# if/else trouble with this program- if statement not printing to console

Tags: python

The program is to measure the length of a string that is entered, but if an integer is entered; it should print "undetectable".

This program should return the output of the `if` statement when it encounters an integer. Instead it just recognizes the `else` statement, even in the case of an integer.
What could I be doing wrong here?

```
def string_length(mystring):
    if type(mystring) == int :
        return "undetectable"
    else:
        return len(mystring) 
mystring=input("Enter the string: ") 
print("The length of the string entered is: " + str(string_length(mystring)))
```

Comment: Your input is a string, so it won't ever be detected as an integer.

Comment: The input is always a string, `type("1") != int`.

Comment: `input("Enter the string: ")` will always return a string, no matter what you enter: `1`, `hello` or `3.141`, so `mystring` (see - _string_!) will be a string. (Yes, the string here is made of string :D)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, input returns a string, so the object will always be a string, even if it is a string of ascii characters that correspond with integers. You will want to use isdigit() to check if the string an integer.

```
if mystring.isdigit():
    return "undetectable"
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `input` will always return a string.

If the user enters `1`, what you get in your variable is the *string* `'1'`, not the integer `1`. This is why your `if` condition never evaluates to `True`.

One way of checking if a string represents a (positive) integer would be to use `isdigit()`:

```
if(mystring.isdigit()):
    return "undetectable"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` function always returns a string. Sometimes that string can represent an input, but you'd need to convert it first using `int()`.

The usual way to check whether the string represents an integer is to try to interpret it as one, using `try`/`except`, and if that fails then assume it isn't:

```
def string_length(my_string):
    try:
        int_value = int(mystring)
        # if no error, then it's an integer
        return "undetectable"
    except ValueError:
        # error; converting it to an int failed. Must be a regular string.
        return len(my_string)
```